# comparing two pandas dataframes with different column names and finding match

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes :

df1:

```
A    B    C
1    ss   123
2    sv   234
3    sc   333
```

df2:

```
A    dd   xc
1    ss   123
```

df2 will always have a single row. How to check whether there is a match for that row of df2, in df1?

Answer (score 4):

Using Numpy comparisons with [`np.all`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.all.html) with parameter `axis=1` for rows:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 3], 'B': ['ss', 'sv', 'sc'], 'C': [123, 234, 333]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1], 'dd': ['ss'], 'xc': [123]})

df3 = df1.loc[np.all(df1.values == df2.values, axis=1),:]
```

Or:

```
df3 = df1.loc[np.all(df1[['B','C']].values == df2[['dd','xc']].values, axis=1),:]
```

---

```
print(df3)
   A   B    C
0  1  ss  123
```

Comment: What if i need to check only specific columns from df2 with df1?  like only check for dd, xc from df2 with B,C of df1?

Comment: `ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().`

Comment: @qwww Can you paste the code snippet giving you error. Also, check if the statements are exactly the same.

Comment: dont use isin, because it match index names, try change index name in second dataframe and it failed...

Comment: @jezrael Yes, Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: `AxisError: axis 1 is out of bounds for array of dimension 0` this is what i am getting

Comment: @qwww Can you please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for that example.

Answer (score 0):

Additional to Sandeep's answer, can do:

```
df1[np.all(df1.values == df2.values,1)].any().any()
```

For getting a boolean.

Or another way:

```
df1[(df2.values==df1.values).all(1)].any().any()
```

Or:

```
pd.merge(df1,df2).equals(df1)
```

Note: both output `True`

Check specific column (same as Sandeep's):

```
df1[col].isin(df2[col]).any()
```

Answer (score 0):

> How to check whether there is a match for that row of df2, in df1?

You can align columns and then check equality of `df1` with the only row of `df2`:

```
df2.columns = df1.columns

res = (df1 == df2.iloc[0]).all(1).any()  # True
```

The benefit of this solution is you aren't subsetting `df1` (expensive), but instead constructing a Boolean dataframe / array (cheap) and checking if all values in at least one row are `True`.

This is still not particularly efficient as you are considering *every* row in `df1` rather than stopping when a condition is satisfied. With numeric data, in particular, there are more efficient solutions.

Comment: what if column numbers are not same?

Comment: @qwww, Then you have a new question :). Seriously, I'm assuming you have `df1` and `df2` as in your question. You can't automate alignment of columns. How is Pandas meant to know `xc` maps to `C`?